# Haproxy logs 200 status code but real response is error code

Tags: lua, haproxy

```
global
    lua-load /etc/haproxy/notify.lua

defaults
    log global
    mode http

frontend http-in
    option httplog
    bind *:80
    timeout client 30s
    default_backend proxies

backend proxies
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 30s
    balance roundrobin

    http-after-response lua.notify

    server node-0 node-0:8080 check
    server node-1 node-1:8080 check
```

I have this simple HAProxy (2.8). Now I open with proxy my custom page where nginx returns 403 error code. So in Postman I see this 403 error code:

[image]

But in haproxy log I see:

> 172.19.0.1:42278 [10/Oct/2023:10:16:07.990] http-in proxies/node-0 0/0/1/47/381 **200** 5878 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "CONNECT ****.io:443
> HTTP/1.1"

So it logs status code 200. Also when I try to get this status code in lua script, it gives me 200:

```
local status_code = tonumber(txn.f:status())
```

Why it's 200? How to get real returned status code from server and not from my backend.